# How to verify application/x-bzip2 type response in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, gzip, bzip2

I am using Python to make api Call and getting unreadable response data from one Post API call.

e.g.Response text looks like below

`�r6�;���&�gr&)i��|!J6.m�����[;ŀ�'���1,�'>B()@�ܪ �D�����n�r/8*�<�QS���5�v�\3t�`

**Post Header :** `'Content-Type':'text/xml','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate'`

**Response Header** contains -> `'Content-Type': 'application/x-bzip2'`

How can I convert this data into a readable format, so that I can validate the response data.

Comment: Use a program that can uncompress `bzip2`.

Comment: Uncompress it? If you don't want a reply with compressed contents then you should make sure the request header includes that information (like the `Accept-Encoding` header you sent).

Comment: @heemayl It's not working i tried  `bz2.decompress(self.response.text)` which gives me an error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` . Also tried to convert into bytes `bz2.decompress(self.response.text.encode())` which gives me an error `OSError: Invalid data stream`

Comment: Don't use `response.text` because the response is not text. Just pass the binary data to bz2. Possibly it's `response.content`, but I don't know what library you're using.